# Why Swift crash report doesn't show the exception name?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, crashlytics

I'm checking the crash report on Crashlytics.

For some crashes there is a clear message like:

```
*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 13 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]
```

But for some other crashes I only have the function name and this message:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001001f3938
```

Is there anything I can do to increase the verbosity of the crash log?

Comment: I don't think anything can be done about it. But you can put breakpoints in your code and see where exactly the app is crashing. Xcode shows the entire stack of how the code executed with the hexadecimal identifier it gives to individual objects(buttons, labels, textfields etc.)

Comment: I'm trying to understand the crash to be able to replicate on xcode.

Comment: That's what I am saying. It is so detailed, that it is difficult to make any sense out of it.

Comment: You don't get a stacktrace you mean ? Are you symbolicating your crash logs ?

Comment: Sure I get the stacktrace but the stacktrace shows only the function name.
Not the exception name. You can see that sometime I get the real reson for the crash (1st message) and sometime I just get  EXC_BREAKPOINT